# How to create an array with same value as string in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create this:

```
"Presentes" => array(
   "Run" => array("numero" => 123, "dv" => 1),
   "Run" => array("numero" => 1234, "dv" => 2),
   "Run" => array("numero" => 12345, "dv" => 3)
)
```

Using same string key.  I need to create something like this recursively with an array:

```
<mine:Presentes> 
<mine:Run> 
<mine:numero>15166706</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>6</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
<mine:Run> 
<mine:numero>15166707</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>4</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
<mine:Run> 
<mine:numero>19358721</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>6</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
<mine:Run>
 <mine:numero>20458780</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>9</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
</mine:Presentes>
```

Comment: yes it's possible using multi dimensional array in php

Comment: You can't like that keys must be unique.

Comment: From a pure data-structure sense, no the associative key names must be unique.  EG: `$Presentes["Run"] = ....` What is the purpose for needing them to have identical key names?

Comment: I need to create something like this recursively with an array
<mine:Presentes> 
<mine:Run> 
<mine:numero>15166706</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>6</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
<mine:Run> 
<mine:numero>15166707</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>4</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
<mine:Run> 
<mine:numero>19358721</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>6</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
<mine:Run>
 <mine:numero>20458780</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>9</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
</mine:Presentes>

Answer (score -1):

Keys must be unique within the array so you would have to add another dimension:

```
$array = array("Presentes" => array(
   array("Run" => array("numero" => 123, "dv" => 1)),
   array("Run" => array("numero" => 1234, "dv" => 2)),
   array("Run" => array("numero" => 12345, "dv" => 3))
));
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [Presentes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Run] => Array
                        (
                            [numero] => 123
                            [dv] => 1
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Run] => Array
                        (
                            [numero] => 1234
                            [dv] => 2
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Run] => Array
                        (
                            [numero] => 12345
                            [dv] => 3
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Or this:

```
$array = array("Presentes" => array("run" => array(
   array("numero" => 123, "dv" => 1),
   array("numero" => 1234, "dv" => 2),
   array("numero" => 12345, "dv" => 3)
)));
```

Which yields:

```
Array
(
    [Presentes] => Array
        (
            [run] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [numero] => 123
                            [dv] => 1
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [numero] => 1234
                            [dv] => 2
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [numero] => 12345
                            [dv] => 3
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: yep.. I did that but isn't that I need to get it. I need to create something like this recursively:
<mine:Presentes> 
<mine:Run> 
<mine:numero>15166706</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>6</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
<mine:Run> 
<mine:numero>15166707</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>4</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
<mine:Run> 
<mine:numero>19358721</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>6</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
<mine:Run>
 <mine:numero>20458780</mine:numero> 
<mine:dv>9</mine:dv> 
</mine:Run> 
</mine:Presentes>